# Shoulder strength imbalance after injury

Tags: injury, shoulders, muscle-imbalance

A few months ago I injured my right shoulder (collar bone area) playing contact sport.

I haven't played or done much training at all since then. I joined a gym recently and they did a body composition analysis thing which showed less muscle mass in my upper right body (where the injury is).

I started doing some training, weights and cardio etc... Nothing massively strenuous and I noticed that with the shoulder press I was struggling with my right side. At the end of the second set my left arm was still going strong but my right arm just couldn't complete the lift.

It wasn't painful, just had no strength. Obviously, I don't want to injure myself and I will try to find someone to speak to in the gym but I was looking for advice on how to balance up my strength.

Should I try less weight until my right shoulder gains more muscle? Should I keep going at this weight but stop when my right arm can't go on? Should I do different weights between my arms?

What's the best approach here?

I hope that I have provided all the required information but if there is anything else that would help I'd be happy to provide it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get medical attention, or talked to a qualified therapist yet? If not please do. Without proper diagnosis it's very hard to tell what the issue with your shoulder is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a doctor, but here's my advice: Since you have no pain in your previously-injured right shoulder during exercise, and it's simply weaker than your other shoulder, then, yes: reduce your work-weight as much as necessary to allow you to complete your intended exercise scheme.

Train your shoulders progressively by, for example, doing three sets of five ("3x5") [overhead shoulder presses](http://startingstrength.com/video/lifts/main-lifts/the_press_with_brent_carter) two or three times per week, increasing your work-weight by an appropriate amount (say, 1 kg to 2.5 kg) each session.  With training, the strength disparity between your shoulders will diminish or disappear.